# selenium fedora xfce amazon EC2

Tags: python, linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xfce

I am running fedora 19 XFCE on EC2, I get this error when i run the python selenium script...

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_PROG (__main__.TEST_PROG)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "selenium_asda.py", line 24, in setUp
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.36.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 60, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.36.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.36.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 61, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.36.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 100, in _wait_until_connectable
    self._get_firefox_output())
WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: \n(process:22490): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion `sys_page_size == 0\' failed\nGtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"\n*** LOG addons.xpi: startup\n*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges\n*** LOG addons.xpi: No changes found\n/usr/lib/firefox/firefox: relocation error: /tmp/tmpxzNZAo/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/platform/Linux_x86-gcc3/components/libwebdriver-firefox-latest.so: symbol _Znwj, version xul24.0 not defined in file libxul.so with link time reference\n' 

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 5.193s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

the script works fine on my local machine...and I think this is related to the desktop settings for XFCE.

I connect to the instance via vnc and can get the full XFCE desktop with no issues.

Any hints?

**SOLVED:**

I downgraded selenium 2.36 to 2.35 and the tests runs OK.

Comment: did you try [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=921066) ?

Comment: I have the same version of firefox firefox-24.0-1.fc19.i686 installed on my local dekstop and also on EC2...but it fails on EC2

Answer (score 2):

That error is due to browser incompatibility. I had the same thing while trying to run FF24. Try the tutorial here to try and get it running with FF22.

[Firefox browser issues with Selenium](http://inkhorn.ca/selenium-python-on-ubuntu-using-firefox/)